# Where should SelectListItem lists go?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

In an MVC application, I have some DropDownLists. In my controller I create the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`s and transfer them to my View. Unfortunately, if there is a validation error, I need to recreate those lists, otherwise the view rendering fails.

In the controller action method I'm doing:

```
var possibilities = _repo.Objects.Select(o=>new SelectListItem(...));
viewmodel.Possibilities = possibilities;
return View(viewmodel);
```

The view-model has the Possibilities property defined like this:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Possibilities { get; set; }
```

And in my view I access it:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(vm=>vm.ThePossibility, vm.Possibilities)
```

The problem is that when the form post action method is called, the view model passed to it has a null for `Possibilities`, so when I call:

```
if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    return View(model);
```

The view doesn't get rendered.

I understand why the propery is null on the post action method, but what's the best way of correcting this? I'd rather not reinitialize those lists.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to re-initialize the lists, you will have to cache them somewhere, such as the session or somewhere else.

Frankly, in most cases, it's just simpler to rebuild them.  You will have to re-assign them every time.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, I should have thought of that. To make this happen automatically I need to introduce some sort of view-states back. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using the [Post-Redirect-Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get); There is a nice pair of attributes described in [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx#prg) that make this very easy to do in ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: If you're referring to #13 in the blog post, then that doesn't apply here.  It's talking about ModelState, which does not include the dropdowns SelectList.  Further, I have huge issues with the TempData approach as when the users refreshes the page TempData is gone and so is your ModelState.  It's fine for a message but not for any real state you need.

Comment: @Mystere - Correct - ModelState is persisted, but the redirect back to the "Get" request means that the method that originally filled the dropdown list options gets to do it all over again.  And as far as a Page Reload losing the ModelState, that is the behavior I (and I believe most others) expect.

Answer (score 1):

I usually cache these somewhere or provide a static class for getting common lists. You can then provide access to these in your model with a getter.

For example:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> _possibilities 
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Possibilities 
{ 
   get
   {
       if (_possibilities == null)
           _possibilities = CommonLists.Possibilities();

       return possibilities;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Accessors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa287786) and JSON ([NetwonSoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)) are your friends.

In a nutshell

1. When you `set` the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property of your model, **serialize it** to a public string property.
2. When your public string property is being `set`, and the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` is not defined (e.g. null), **deserialize** the string property to the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property of your model.
3. In your view, embed the serialized string so that it is persisted between posts to the server.  (Eg. `@Html.HiddenFor(...)`)

**Model**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Selections
    {
        get
        {
            return selections;
        }
        set
        {
            selections= value;
            // serialize SelectListItems to a json string
            SerializedSelections = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        }
    }
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selections;

    public string SerializedSelections
    {
        get
        {
            return serializedSelections;
        }
        set
        {
            serializedSelections = value;
            if(Selections == null)
            {
                // SelectListItems aren't defined.  Deserialize the string to the list
                Selections = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<SelectListItem>>(value);
            }
        }
    }
    string serializedSelections;
}
```

**Razor View**

```
<form>
...
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SerializedSelections)
...
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SomeProperty, Model.Selections)
</form>
```